# MooseX::Declare and Perl EPIC (Eclipse IDE)?

Tags: eclipse, perl, editor, eclipse-plugin, moose

How can I get support for jumping to Moose methods using Eclipse with the EPIC plugin? (Using F3)

They're declared like

```
class Point {
  method getDistance { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't be easy... The grammar for Perl in EPIC in written using ANTLR, a Java based, parsers' generator. It is statically compiled into Java code, so if you want to change the default Perl grammar, or add to it, you have to dive into ANTLR grammar and recompile the EPIC plugin.

Parts of the grammar can be found e.g. [here](http://e-p-i-c.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/e-p-i-c/org.epic.perleditor/src/org/epic/core/parser/perl.g).